# How to make a random number appear as many times as I want

Tags: javascript, random

So I want a random number (picture) from a code below to appear as much time as I want. In this case I am dealing with pictures. Let' say I want to make a picture named 1.png just to be printed on screen 4 times excatly and then let's say pictures 5.png and 6.png all together to be returned 10 times (it can be 3 times 5.png, 7 times 6.png and other ways we can get to 10) and so on for other examples. How can I do it, since I have no idea at all ?

I hope I explained the right way what I want, and I hope anyone can help, thank you for your help.

```js
function RandomImage() {
  return (Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)).toString() + ".png";
}
```

Comment: trying to print random image multiple times ?

Comment: You'll need another function to randomize the counts (or call the current function, if the limits are suitable), then store the image names into an array using the randomized amount.

Comment: @FaizalHussain yes but in this case I have ten images name (1.png,2.png...) and I want let say picture 1.png be shown excatly 4 times, and lets say 4.png excatly 5 times, 6.png and 8.png together to be appear 12 times etc. This logic!

Comment: @Teemu you have an idea how the code can look or at least help with it since I am not that good in js.

Comment: No, I don't, because I've no clue what "_just to be returned_" means in practice.

Comment: @Teemu to be printed on screen. Probably I said it the wrong way.

Comment: Different solution: first create an array with 10 "1"s, a random number of "5"s and enough "6"s to get to 10 and so on. Then *shuffle* (randomize) the array and give the values in index order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by setting up a datastructure which keeps track of how many times a specific number has already been returned.
For this purpose we can utilize JavaScript's **Map** object.

So the basic idea is this:

- Inside the random number function we generate a random number
- Look into the map how many times we already returned that number
- In case it matches e.g. 1==10 times we go back to step 1
- If there's no match increment the map entry for the given number and ultimately return the number

Here's an example:

```js
let randomNumbers = new Map();
let maxNumbers = 10;
for (let a = 0; a <= maxNumbers; a++) {
  randomNumbers.set(a, 0);
}

function RandomImage() {
  let failed = false;
  let random;
  do {
    failed = false;
    random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * maxNumbers);
    switch (random) {
      case 1:
        if (randomNumbers.get(1) == 4) {
          failed = true;
        }
        break;
      case 5:
        if (randomNumbers.get(5) + randomNumbers.get(6) == 10) {
          failed = true;
        }
        break;
      case 6:
        if (randomNumbers.get(5) + randomNumbers.get(6) == 10) {
          failed = true;
        }
        break;

    }
  }
  while (failed);
  randomNumbers.set(random, randomNumbers.get(random) + 1);
  return random.toString() + ".png";
}

for (let a = 0; a < 50; a++) {
  console.log(RandomImage());
}
```

Comment: hey may I ask you why we have in case 5 and case 6 literally the same thing ?

Comment: Sure! Because 5 and 6 should do the same thing (sum up to 10) but in a switch/case block we can't have multiple conditions in a single case statement e.g. `case (5 || 6):`. (Well, that's not entirely true but it's cleaner and easier to read if we separate each condition)

Comment: does the number of a case matters could it be case 2 and case 3 ?

Comment: Sorry! I didn't understand that - what do you mean?

Comment: I am just asking the name of the cases (case 5 and case 6) can it be case 2 and 3 does the number has any meaning ?

Comment: Ah, yes, we are comparing the generated random number: `random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * maxNumbers);` in the `switch(random) {}` block. Inside we can make exceptions for specific numbers e.g. 5 and 6. According to our logic if the the number of times 5 and 6 have been returned sums up to 10 we don't want RandomImage() to return that number -> thus it sets the boolean `failed` to false and generates a new random number.

Comment: oh okay this is a bit confusing for me since I am not that good in js. Okay let's say I want to check for 7.png 8.png 9.png do I make it case 7 ,8,9 and repate it 3 times with cases ( case 7,8,9)

Comment: Yes exactly - or if it should do the same thing and you want to combine that into one condition you could write: `case [7,8,9].find(num => num === random):` I wanted to avoid that though since it's a bit harder to understand than having a single condition per case.

Comment: Okay so basically if I want to check 7.png, 8.png, 9.png to be printed 8 times I do it after case 6 right? And write inside the case `if (randomNumbers.get(7) + randomNumbers.get(7) + andomNumbers.get(9) == 8) ...` and write the same thing for case 7, case 8, case 9 ? So I follow this kind of logic?!

Comment: Yes! The order doesn't matter though - you can write that condition wherever you want in the switch block.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to duplicate a string you could use a function like this

```
function repeat(item, number=1) {
  return Array.from({length: number}).fill(item)
}
```

You can then call it like:

```
repeat(RandomImage(), 3) // -> ["1.jpeg", "1.jpeg", "1.jpeg"]
```

Comment: I think I am not asking the right way and it's my fault. I have like a grid in html 3x3 which in some places has like fixed pictures and some other places I am puting random pictures which I dowloaded but lets say out of 9 places I have 5 places which I can put random picture on it and I want 1.png to be appeard two times on it and 3.png to be appeard three times on it on random place.

Comment: `document.getElementById("myImg1").src = RandomImage();` I generate a random picture one the grid-item like this.

Comment: @qoke This is a very nice answer to what you've actually asked. If you can't apply the answer, please ask a new question about how to use it. But, you've to show an attempt how you actually tried to use the answer. Take time to create your question, that way you can ask what you really need, we're not mind readers.

Comment: @Teemu Yes okay, I agree.

Comment: If you want to make a list with 5 elements in it using the above, assuming you have vars for 1 and 3 you can do something like `[...repeat(imgOne, 2), ...repeat(imgThree, 3)]` this will give you an list containing 2 ones and 3 threes. From there you can look into a shuffling algorithm or ways to pull a random value from the array.